# how do write a list of string into a csv file in python?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of strings with spaces, periods, commas and semi colons and I'm wondering how do I get these into a csv file? I need each list of strings to correspond to one line.

Comment: You will need to be more specific.  What format do you have, and how do you want it mapped to CSV?  Give examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('my.csv', 'w') as handle:
    handle.write('\n'.join(list_of_strings))
```

?
We need more info on your "list of strings" to know if you need to do any more than that.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look to the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module  (especially the [examples part](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples) )?